# Converting Lead Duplicate Error

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am converting leads through apex using the LeadConvertClass methods. But sometimes the converted lead information already exists on the system under a contact record, which gives me the following error message:

> System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record.
>   We recommend you use an existing record instead.: []

Is there a way to check if the contact already exists? (A simpler way then checking for all the email, firstnames , lastnames)

Comment: A selective query for that record, you don't need to query all of them and parse them just select where email, firstName, LastName = what is on the Lead you are converting. If you get a result it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Jesse Milburn so there is not an easier to check it straight through the LeadConvertionClass?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Even if it a duplicate and you want to merge them you have to get the ids of the duplicate record and set them with LeadConvert class methods.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_methods

Comment: I am currently using the LeadConvert Class method but I couln't find any proper way to check if the contact already exists with it, so I though I might be missing something. For example if I use the getContactId()  it returns null in this case

Comment: yeah, because that is for merging records. In which case you would have to set that to the contact you want to merge with.